# Difference between the verbs 探す, 捜す, and 探る？

Tags: word-choice, nuances, usage, word-usage

To my understanding, they all mean "to search for" but I'm unsure of the differences between the two and in what contexts I should be using one over the other. (Edit) Just found out about 捜す. Is there any difference between this and 探す?

Comment: I would translate 探る as “to explore” while 探す is to search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add examples to MA-Moustache's answer.

探す for 'looking for what you lost/don't have':

- 鍵/仕事を探す - 探る is not possible here

探る for 'explore/try to find out'

- 原因を探る - 探す is not impossible, but less idiomatic.
- 様子を探る - 探す is impossible.

There are cases where both can be used:

- ポケットを探す means *searching for something particular in the pocket* while ポケットを探る means more *fumbling in the pocket to see what the subject has*.
- 海底を探る is *to explore the seabed* while 海底を探す
  may be used when you look for something you dropped in the sea, which is not very likely.

Source: [a thesaurus entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/4380/meaning/m1u/%E6%8E%A2%E3%82%8B/)

Answer (score 3):

The verbs **探す** and **探る** both mean "to search for," but they are used slightly differently in Japanese.

**探す** is typically used when actively searching for something that you don't currently possess or know the location of. It can be used in a variety of contexts, such as searching for a lost item, looking for a specific person or thing, or trying to find information on a particular topic.

**探る**, on the other hand, is used more specifically to refer to physically searching for something by looking around or inspecting a place or object. It is often used when trying to find something hidden or concealed, such as searching a room for a hidden key or checking a car for a malfunction.

In general, **探す** is more commonly used in everyday language, while **探る** is used more specifically in contexts where you are physically searching for something.